# Laravel+Vue webpack loading chunks from specific path

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

In a Laravel+Vue project I trying to compiling my assets to `public_html/dist/` instead `/public`. I change my *webpack.mix.js* to this:

```
mix.setPublicPath('public_html');

mix.webpackConfig({
  ...
  output: {
    chunkFilename: 'chunks/[name].[contenthash].js',
    path: __dirname + '/public_html/dist/',
    clean: true
  }
});
```

and the output is:

```
public_html/
├──dist/
│   ├── chunks/
│   ├── css/
│   ├── fonts/
│   ├── images/
│   ├── js/
```

Now I have issue with loading **fonts** and loading **chunks** specially in my dashboard that is use vue components and vue router.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea about this, but your problem is that it is trying to load `localhost:8000/dist` instead of `localhost:8000/public_html/dist`, right ?

Comment: Yes you're right.@matiaslauriti

Comment: Are you using `mix(...)`, `url(...)`, `asset(...)` ?